# Link PieChart to DB

Tags: java, database, charts, jfreechart

I'm having issues to create a Pie Chart with Database, everything looks to be right but it won't generate the Chart. I have set SELECT statement correctly, converted the Text into Integer, set the Chart with the right link with the DB, but it still doesn't work.

Would someone know what is going on? Thanks.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;

public class pie2 {
    JTextField open = null;
    JTextField close = null;

    public void pie2() {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {

            String serverName = "127.0.0.1";
            String mydatabase = "test";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverName + "/" + mydatabase;
            String usernameConn = "root";
            String passwordConn = "";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usernameConn, passwordConn);

            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            if (stmt.execute("select count(*) as Open from tb_tickets where status = 'open'")) {
                rs = stmt.getResultSet();
                rs.next();
                open.setText(rs.getString("Open"));

            }
            if (stmt.execute("select count(*) as Close from tb_tickets where status = 'closed'")) {
                rs = stmt.getResultSet();
                rs.next();
                close.setText(rs.getString("Close"));
            }

            int openE = Integer.parseInt(open.getText());
            int closedE = Integer.parseInt(close.getText());

            DefaultPieDataset pieDataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
            pieDataset.setValue("Open", new Integer(openE));
            pieDataset.setValue("Close", new Integer(closedE));

            JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart("CSC408 Mark Distribution", pieDataset, true, true, false);
            // Title
            // Dataset
            // Show legend
            // Use tooltips
            // Configure chart to generate URLs?
            try {
                ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(new File("/Users/Levys/Documents/workspace/chart.jpg"), chart, 500, 300);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Problem occurred creating chart.");
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // handle any errors
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new pie2();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your main() method only calls the no-arg constructor of your class. You probably meant to then call the pie2() method using that instance. Or you meant to have you method actually be the constructor.

Comment: I think it would be to then call the pie2() method using that instance

Comment: Try `org.jfree.data.jdbc.JDBCPieDataset`.